Upper bound for $\sum_{k=1}^n a_{k}b_{n+1-k}$ with $\sum_{k=0}^{j} a_k b_{j-k} =1$
Problem 1: Set $a_0 = b_0 =1$. Given $n \in \mathbb{N} $ and real numbers $a_i, b_i \in [0,1)$ for $i\in \{ 1,2,3~ ...~n\}$ with $$\sum_{k=0}^{j} a_k b_{j-k} =1$$ all $j \le n$. Then I conjecture that we must have  $$ \sum_{k=1}^n a_{k}b_{n+1-k} < 1~.$$
Proving this conjecture (Problem 1) for all $n$ would greatly help solving a $0,1$-polynomial conjecture. Note that one can (by induction) asume that  $a_i$ or $b_i$ is nonzero, because if both were zero then the conjecture would be false for $n=i-1$.
I give proof for the first few values for $n$: if $n=1$ the statement is trivial. For $n=2$ we have $$a_1+ b_1 =1 \qquad a_2 + b_2 +a_1 b_1 = 1~.$$
And we want to prove $a_1 b_1 +a_1 b_2 < 1$. This is quite easy: $$1 = (a_2 + b_2 +a_1 b_1)(a_1+ b_1 ) > a_2 b_1 +a_1 b_2 ~.$$
For $n=3$ we have $$a_1+ b_1 =1 \qquad a_2 + b_2 +a_1 b_1 = 1 \qquad a_3  + a_2 b_1 + a_1 b_2 + b_3 =1 ~.$$  Then we can conclude $$ 1 = a_3  + a_2 b_1 + a_1 b_2 + b_3 = (a_1 +b_1)(a_3 +b_3) + (a_2 b_1 + a_1 b_2)(a_2 + b_2 + a_1 b_1 ) = (a_1 b_3 + a_3 b_1 + \text{more terms}) + (a_2 b_2 a_1 +a_2 b_2 b_1 + \text{more terms} ) > a_3 b_1 + a_1 b_3 + a_2 b_2 (a_1 + b_1) = a_3 b_1 + a_2 b_2 + a_1 b_3~.$$ The proof consists of multiplication by 1 and dropping some "lower terms". Of course one has to verify that the "more terms" I cut are positive for a strict inequality. I expect a similar approach to work for $n=4$, but I couldn't see it.
However, I can not generalize this nor can I handle larger values of $n$ by hand. Does anybody now anything about this structure, can construct a counterexample or has some clever proof idea?
One can express $b_k$ as a polynomial in $a_i$. Here are explicit formulas obtained from power series inversion:
$$b_k =1+ \sum_{j=1}^k \sum_{\substack{m_1, m_2, \dots\\\sum_{i}im_i= j}}  (m_1+m_2+m_3 ...)! \prod_{i = 1}^j \frac{ (-a_i)^{m_i}}{m_i!}$$
or as a determinante
$$b_k=1+ \sum_{r=1}^k(-1)^r
\begin{vmatrix}
a_1 & a_0 & 0 & 0 & \dotsm & 0& 0 & 0\\
a_2 & a_1 & a_0 & 0 & \dotsm & 0 & 0& 0\\
a_3 & a_2 & a_1 & a_0 & \dotsm & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots &\vdots & \vdots\\
a_{r-2} & a_{r-3} & a_{r-4} & a_{r-5} & \dotsm & a_1 & a_0 & 0\\
a_{r-1} & a_{r-2} & a_{r-3} & a_{r-4} & \dotsm & a_2 & a_1 & a_0\\
a_{r} & a_{r-1} & a_{r-2} & a_{r-3} & \dotsm & a_3 & a_2 & a_1
\end{vmatrix}~.$$

If I understand correctly, the $b_i$ are uniquely determined by the $a_j$ with $j\leq i$, and in fact they are polynomials in these $a_j$. Do you have explicit expressions for these polynomials $b_i(a_1,\ldots,a_i)$?

@Servaes Yes the $b_i$ are polynomials in $(a_1, a_2 ... a_i)$ and one can give an explicit expression for them with a Wronskian determinante or with a (horrible looking) sum(I will post equationsfor everything tomorrow). The problem with this approach is that $a_i \in [0,1)$ for all $i$ does not imply that $b_i(a_1 , a_2 ... a_i)$ is in $[0,1)$. Hence if we define the expression that we want to bound as a function of $a_1, a_2, a_3 ... a_n$ we can not choose $[0,1)^n$ as the domain (and I can not tell how the right domain looks like).

Thanks, indeed I feared the domain of the $a_i$ would then be an issue. But then again there may lie some insight. Curious to see your update tomorrow, +1 for an interesting question.

I might be interesting to see your proof for the case $n=3$.

@MartinR I added a proof for $n=3$.

The conjectured inequality does not hold in general. A counterexample for $n=4$ is
$$
    (a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4) = (1, \frac{22}{25}, 0, \frac 1 5, 0) \, ,\\
    (b_0, b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4) = (1, \frac{3}{25}, \frac{559}{625}, \frac{202}{15625}, \frac{376806}{390625}) \, .
$$
$\sum_{k=0}^{j} a_k b_{j-k} =1$ holds for $1 \le j \le 4$, but
$$
a_1 b_4 + a_2 b_3 + a_3 b_2 + a_4 b_1 = \frac{10036607}{9765625} > 1 \, .
$$
The example was found by trying random coefficients, and verified with PARI/GP:
                  GP/PARI CALCULATOR Version 2.15.4 (released)
         arm64 running darwin (aarch64/GMP-6.3.0 kernel) 64-bit version
                  compiled: Dec 14 2023, clang version 16.0.6
                            threading engine: single
                 (readline v8.2 enabled, extended help enabled)

                     Copyright (C) 2000-2022 The PARI Group

PARI/GP is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and comes 
WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY WHATSOEVER.

Type ? for help, \q to quit.
Type ?18 for how to get moral (and possibly technical) support.

parisize = 8000000, primelimit = 500000
? 
? a1 = 22/25; a2 = 0; a3 = 1/5; a4 = 0;
? b1 = 3/25; b2 = 559/625; b3 = 202/15625 ; b4 = 376806/390625;
? 
? a1 + b1
%3 = 1
? b2 + a1 * b1 + a2
%4 = 1
? b3 + a1 * b2 + a2 * b1 + a3
%5 = 1
? b4 + a1 * b3 + a2 * b2 + a3 * b1 + a4
%6 = 1
? 
? a1 * b4 + a2 * b3 + a3 * b2 + a4 * b1
%7 = 10036607/9765625


Thank you so much!

@M.E.W.: It seems that $\sum_{k=1}^n a_{k}b_{n+1-k}$ can not become much larger than one. The largest value that I got after trying $>10^9$ random coefficients in $[0, 1)^4$ was $1.045$.
